# Getting Individual Emails With Firebase in MailApp Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I cannot seem to find any resources which offers me clarity on how to accomplish this.

I have built an app which allows users to post information from a regular UIViewController, which appears inside a cell on a UITableView. When a user views each cell, they can click on the cell- which opens up MailApp so they can email them. Instead? The current logged in users email appears, not each individual email when different users create posts.

So for example, if you created an account and created a post and then I logged in and went to view your post in the UITableViewController? My email appears in MailApp when I tap on the cell, not your email..

I have inserted code below in `setToRecipients`, but it's not working. How can I fix this?

```
//Compose Email Message

func configuredMailComposedViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Hey! I saw you on Spaide. Looking to connect.")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Hey there! I had a few questions and was hoping you could help.", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line does *mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!])* or what you think it should be doing?

Comment: @Jay I revised my question, hopefully that explains better what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: I helps. I still would like to know what the function is of the line in my prior comment.

Comment: It gives authorization to get info for Firebase users.

Comment: This component *(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!* gets the current user email; i.e. the currently logged in users email. Then it passes this users email to the mail message and makes it a **recipient**. If you want to send to multiple recipients, you would use *mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["to_user@example.com", "another_user@example.com])*

Comment: @Jay Yes, I know this, but how would I automatically get it through Firebase? Not manually putting it in myself. Like I mentioned above, if I tap on your cell in UITableView, I would want your email to pop up and so on, for every user who posts..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what  you are asking but I think the answer is to perform a query on Firebase, which will return the user nodes you are interested in. Iterate over those nodes and build an array of email addresses and then pass that array to *mailComposerVC.setToRecipients*. If you need something more can you clarify your question so we understand the scope of the project and task? You may also want to include the code your have tried so far that isn't working. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)